# static css not show in express jade

Tags: css, node.js, coffeescript, express, pug

edited for the ilollar answer(same problem)
i have app.coffee :

```
pp.configure ->
  publicDir = "#{__dirname}/public"

app.set "views", viewsDir
app.set "view engine", "jade"

app.use(stylus.middleware debug: true, src: viewsDir, dest: publicDir, compile: compileMethod)
app.use(express.static(publicDir))

compileMethod = (str, path) ->
  stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .set('compress', true)


app.get "/pag",(req,res) ->
  res.render "pag",
  title: "test",
```

in /stylesheet/pag.jade:

```
...
link(rel='stylesheet', href='pag/css/bootstrap.min.css')
...
```

when im go to "myserver:9090/pag" the page not load the bootstrap.min.css.
i get the following error:

```
source :(my folder of proyects)/views/pag/css/bootstrap.min.styl
dest : (my folder of proyects)/public/pag/css/bootstrap.min.css
read : (my folder of proyects)/views/pag/css/bootstrap.min.styl
Error: ENOENT, open '(my folder)/views/pag/css/bootstrap.min.styl'
```

Where am i wrong? i am probably missing something.. any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, if you haven't set up ExpressJS to serve static files, you'll want to do that:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Then, remove the "public" from your stylesheet call:

`link(rel='stylesheet', href='/pag/css/bootstrap.min.css')`

You're setting "public" as the app root directory that static files are being served from, so there's no need to specify "public" in your call - "public" is now the root.

**Update:**
What is your `viewsDir` set to? Since you've set the Stylus middleware's source to that directory, that's where it is looking for the `styl` to render.

You're setting "public" as the destination directory - if you include "public" in the call, it'll just make another public directory under public, which isn't what you want.

Try reorganizing the stylesheets in the project to something like this:

```
/stylesheets
  /pag
    /css
      bootstrap.min.styl
```

Then change your middleware to this:

`app.use(stylus.middleware debug:true, src:'/stylesheets', dest: publicDir, compile: compileMethod)`

Comment: mi view dir is :

   `viewsDir  = "#{__dirname}/views"`

Comment: You're certain that `bootstrap.min.styl` is in `/views/pag/css`? According your error, it can't find the file in that directory.

Comment: i dont have a bootstrap.min.styl ... just a bootstrap.min.css in /public/pag/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Why are you trying to use the Stylus middleware if you don't need to render Stylus?

Comment: I use the Stylus middleware for my css not for all css (plugins css)

Comment: Is your link path starting with a `/`? Like this: `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/pag/css/bootstrap.min.css')`

Comment: yes i try with a "/"('/pag/css/bootstrap.min.css'), ""('pag/css/bootstrap.min.css') ,"//" ('//pag/css/bootstrap.min.css')?

Comment: Everything should be working then. I've tested everything myself, and it is serving the CSS fine. I've made a Gist showing my working example (including the folder structure). Hopefully it will help. https://gist.github.com/3189870